# Not found an answer addressing getting Python3.6 working in Xcode8.2.1

Tags: xcode8, python-3.6

Tried many variations, but would like to run Python3.6 inside Xcode8

terminal (which Python3) indicates py exec located in /library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/versions/3.6/bin/Python3.6.  Actually there appears to be an exec in /3.6 & /bin.  I have tried both in my Xcode schemes with no luck. The only Python in \usr\bin\python launches Python2.7.

when I edit schemes in Xcode and run I receive a message - 'problem launching using POSIX_SPAWN'.  I can find no Pythonw for version 3.6.  Using Pythonw launches 2.7.

New to use of Python.  What am I missing????